# CSS style is not applied to website after saving (running on XAMPP localhost)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, xampp

I recently started with PHP and so I also started using XAMPP, for the last two days when i change code in the CSS file at first it does not update this on the website. like last night I changed something and only this morning when I started it up again it was applied. XAMPP is online with ProFTPD, Apache and MySQL running, the Network is also online. Why is this? It has only been like this last 2 days before that it worked fine.

Tried to restart everything and changing the file path.

Comment: Could be cache ... just check your browser or the application you use

Comment: Open the app in incognito mode, or delete cache

Comment: i think the issue is not related to useing Xampp or not, I think the browser itself applying a cache for the CSS file.
do you use google chrome?

Comment: I'm sorry still very new to all of this. Check the browser or app for what?

Comment: @MidzElwekil yes i use chrome.

Comment: Press ctrl + f5 for a hard reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is not related to using Xampp, i think the browser you use is caching the css file which means you won't be able to get the updated CSS each time your refresh your page.

if you are using Google Chrome you will need to go to the browser settings and disabled the cache mode in the development version, and to do this use the following steps:

1: Inspect this page or any page (<kbd>F12</kbd> if you are using Windows).

2: press <kbd>F1</kbd> and the settings will be opened to you.

3: at the Network section at the right side under Elements check (Disable Cache Whilte DevTools is open)

4: close everything and open it again and you will be able to get the updated CSS style each time you update this file

there's also another solution, is to change the style URL version each time your update the style file like this => siteURL/style.css?ver=1.1.161017 (Adding Ver=number) will force the browser to update the cached CSS file

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This could be a caching issue.

Having Chrome as active window try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (forcing cache purge) on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyboard shortcut to open an Incognito window:

```
Windows, Linux, or Chrome OS: Press Ctrl + Shift + n.
Mac: Press ⌘ + Shift + n.
```

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a caching issue.

Fix: Inspect this page or any page (F12 if you are using Windows) 2: press F1 and the settings will be opened to you. 3: at the Network section at the right side under Elements check (Disable Cache While DevTools is open) 4: close everything and open it again and you will be able to get the updated CSS style each time you update this file.

Thanks to everyone who helped really appreciate it!